# Hibernate 5 Criteria Join for One to Many relationship

Tags: hibernate, join, hibernate-criteria, jpa-criteria

Code for join Query

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery<SchoolTO> cquery = builder.createQuery(SchoolTO.class);
Root<SchoolTO> root = cquery.from(SchoolTO.class);
Join<SchoolTO, StudentTO> join = root.join(SchoolTO_.studentList);  
cquery.select(root);
cquery.where(builder.equal(join.get(StudentTO_.name),  "john"));
cquery.distinct(true);
List<School> list = session.createQuery(cquery).getResultList();
```

School class structure

```
public class School
{
  private List<Student> list;
}
```

Student class structure

```
public class Student
{
  private School school;
}
```

Data

- School1 -> John, Mathew, William, Megan, Daisy
- School2 -> John,William, Samantha
- School3 -> Daisy, Mathew

Actual Result from Join Hibernate code

- School1 -> John, Mathew, William, Megan, Daisy
- School2 -> John, William, Samantha

Expected Result

- School1 -> John
- School2 -> John

The hibernate join gets me all schools with student name "john". But when I access the list of student objects inside school object it has students of all names. I am trying to achieve the one under expected result. Let me know what I am wrongly doing here. Thanks in advance